# Matrix class in c++ assignment operator

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a Matrix class in c++. I am having problems trying to get the assignment operator to work. At this point I am lost. The issue is that I am getting an error saying that "vector subscript is out of range". If I take this code away `this->size = A.size;` from the assignment overloading operator the compiler doesn't complain. The assignment operator is supposed to return a reference to the Matrix object. I tried creating a new Matrix object but that gave me the same error. Any hints?

```
**Matrix.hpp**

class Matrix
{
private:
    int size;           //size of matrix
    double value;
    std::vector<double> M;
public:
...
}

**Header.cpp**

Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& A) 
{
    if (this == &A)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    else
    {
        this->size = A.size; // this is causing problems
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're copying the size, but not the values. Indexing error may then occur when you're trying to use the pseudo-copied matrix, accessing inexistent index in vector `M`.

Comment: You don't seem to be an expert in C++. Why are you doing this? Just to learn or do you have some application that needs matrix math? If you have some application, then use some of the available libraries. One good library is armadillo http://arma.sourceforge.net/ . It's way more efficient than anything you want to do here by youself. Writing matrix operations is a very tricky business. Don't do this unless you know what you want to achieve and you know you can do it.

Comment: your codes doesnt even work, you cannot call a constructor directly.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I am not an expert, but I am trying to learn C++! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign one matrix to another, you not only need to change the size data member, but also need to change the other data members such as resizing the vector of doubles.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that, I have fixed it now :)